# What are the units of a tensor product of rings?

Tags: tensor-products, algebras

Let $R$ and $S$ be commutative $k$-algebras, for some commutative ring $k$. All rings are assumed to have the identity.

Let $U(R)$ denote the group of invertible elements of $R$. What can we say about $U(R\otimes_k S)$?

Is something like
$$U(R\otimes_k S)\cong U(R)\times U(S)/U(k)$$
true?

I.e. can we express it for example in terms of the pushout?

Cheers.

Comment: If this question can even be partially answered, for example under strong assumptions, such as assuming that $k$ is a PID or even a field, it would still be something.

Comment: I am not sure whether you are familiar with this. Check out this link https://mathoverflow.net/a/57513/58056

Comment: Thank you. Seems interesting, ii) in particular.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373506  shows that under rather strict circumstances the units are as suggested. For a small example where the result is different, let R = S = k[X]/<X^2> where k is the field with 2 elements, i.e. GF(2). U(k)={1}. Let Y be the image of X in k[X]/<X^2>. The units in R and S are 1 and 1+Y.  The other 2 elements 0, Y are not invertible.  So the cardinality of U(R)×U(S) is 4.

The 5 units in the tensor product are:
1(x)1 + Y(x)Y  and the 4 expected units
1(x)1, (1+Y)(x)1, 1(x)(1+Y), (1+Y)(x)(1+Y)

So the cardinality of U(R)(×)U(S)/U(k) is 5.

Comment: Cheers for the link and the example.